# Aggregate by ID, count on date field and sum on time field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

Input Dataframe:

| ID | DATE | PERSONAL_AUX | OUTBOUND_AUX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/3/2022 | 0:09:00 | 0:00:08 |
| 1 | 1/4/2022 | 0:19:00 | 0:00:40 |
| 1 | 1/5/2022 | 0:13:00 | 0:00:33 |
| 1 | 1/6/2022 | 0:08:00 | 0:00:22 |
| 1 | 1/7/2022 | 0:13:00 | 0:00:13 |
| 2 | 1/3/2022 | 0:13:50 | 0:00:15 |
| 2 | 1/4/2022 | 0:14:00 | 0:00:33 |
| 2 | 1/5/2022 | 0:09:00 | 0:00:21 |
| 2 | 1/6/2022 | 0:14:00 | 0:00:12 |
| 3 | 1/3/2022 | 0:14:50 | 0:00:17 |
| 3 | 1/4/2022 | 0:15:00 | 0:00:34 |
| 3 | 1/5/2022 | 0:10:00 | 0:00:23 |
| 3 | 1/6/2022 | 0:15:00 | 0:00:14 |
| 3 | 1/7/2022 | 0:14:50 | 0:00:17 |
| --- | -------- | ------------ | ------------ |

Output Dataframe:
group by ID, count the Date as date worked, sum of personal_aux and sum of outbound_aux

| ID | Day_worked | Sum_personal_AUX | Sum_outbound_aux |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1:02:00 | 0:1:56 |
| 2 | 4 | 0:50:50 | 0:1:21 |
| 3 | 5 | 1:09:00 | 0:1:45 |

Can someone guide, in doing aggregate over a time column in pyspark. Thanks in Advance

Comment: convert your time to seconds, and sum it

Comment: @Steven, can you help me do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
import datetime

def secscon(x):     
    sec = x     
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec))
    
df = input_df \
    .withColumn('PERSONAL_AUX_SEC', F.unix_timestamp(F.col('PERSONAL_AUX'), 'H:mm:ss')) \
    .withColumn('OUTBOUND_AUX_SEC', F.unix_timestamp(F.col('OUTBOUAND_AUX'), 'H:mm:ss')) \
    .withColumn('ID', F.col('ID').cast('int'))
    .groupBy('ID') \
    .agg(
       F.count('DATE').alias('Days_worked'),
       F.sum('PERSONAL_AUX_SEC').alias('sum_personal_aux').cast('double'),
       F.sum('OUTBOUND_AUX_SEC').alias('sum_outbound_aux').cast('double')
    )) 
    
schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('ID',T.IntegerType(),True),
    T.StructField('Days_worked',T.IntegerType(),True),
    T.StructField('sum_personal_aux',T.StringType(),True),
    T.StructField('sum_outbound_aux',T.StringType(), True)
])  
    
df1 = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1] , secscon(x[2]), secscon(x[3]))).toDF(schema)
```